# Removing DC in Analog Filter

Tags: operational-amplifier, audio, dc-offset, analog-filter

*Overview*

I am working on an analog circuit that accepts input from four differential microphone inputs, amplifies, completes some basic filtering, and outputs a single rudimentary average of the inputs.

[image: Filter path schematic section]

The schematic of the filter path comprises,

1. for each microphone input

- a differential to single-ended conversion
- high-pass filter
- low-pass (antialiasing) filter

2. a summer and averaging node (a divide*emphasized text* by four)
3. a final stage gain

The current design features potentiometers to support limited adjustment of gain and HPF cut-off frequency.

Note that where the schematic denotes Mic2-4, these paths mirror the filter path shown for Mic1

*Issue*

The circuit works in practise, however, there is a DC offset appearing at the output that, depending on the gain (configured by the pots) can exceed 180 mV. When tracing the offset, it first appears downstream of capacitor “C5” as indicated in the equivalent schematic section above and has a magnitude of < 7 mV. The offset subsequently appears throughout the remainder of the schematic up to the output.

We’re not certain of the origins of the DC offset, but assume it is from the opamp p/n TS972IYQT.

The offset can be managed at the output by the addition of a DC blocking capacitor; however, the preference is to eliminate the offset in its entirety.

We are limited at present by the number of footprints on the PCB, so we will be forced to remove and add components with flying leads. So far, by way of simulation, we believe we can add series DC blocking capacitors adjacent to “R11” and “R20” requiring some trade-off on the filter response.

I’d like to know, if possible is the following,

1. if anyone can identify any issues in the schematic that may result in the offset?
2. if anyone has any recommendations on the schematic that could potentially remove the offset at all active stages?

Comment: Just a quick thought. Try placing the high pass filter *after* the low-pass filter. Can you arrange that?

Comment: Power supplies are not really "symmetric". The final stage gain should also introduce some "amplifying" offset ...

Comment: Have you tried simulating the circuit and checking the op-amp offset voltages in their data sheets?

Answer (score 1):

Quite possibly it's caused by the dc leakage current through C5 which flows to ground through P2 and causes a voltage drop across it. This is then integrated at dc by the filter and amplified further down the line.

If the dc leakage current through C5 is say 350 nA then the dc voltage generated across P2 is 350 nA * 20k = 7 mV.

If C5 is an electrolytic then I would suggest using a less leaky capacitor such as a ceramic.

Comment: The capacitor, and all others in this schematic, are ceramic.

Answer (score 0):

The TS972 op amp has about 200 nA of input bias current.   That
means that the input resistance driving the (+) and (-) pins
should be equal, or a net I*R voltage will be generated (and amplified).

Simplest way to get around this, is to DC-block between the
sum amplifier and the final stage, and to put a (circa 15k ohm)
resistor between ground and the (+) input of the final op amp.